# Steps involved in creating a pod in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

How does Kubernetes create Pods?

I.e. what are the sequential steps involved in creating a Pod, is  it implemented in Kubernetes?

Any code reference in Kubernetes repo would also be helpful.

Comment: If you have a kubernetes cluster with `kubectl` configured to talk to it, you can use `kubectl run`, the way it is described in http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pods/single-container/#creating-a-pod.

Comment: what do you mean, "implemented" ?

Answer (score 1):

A **Pod** is described in a definition file, and ran as a set of Docker containers on a given host which is part of the Kubernetes cluster, much like `docker-compose` does, but with several differences.

Precisely, a Pod always contains multiple Docker containers, even though, only the containers defined by the user are usually visible through the API: A Pod has one container that is a placeholder generated by the Kubernetes API, that will hold the IP for the Pod (so that when a Pod is restarted, it's actually the client containers that are restarted, but the placeholder container remains and keeps the same IP, unlike in straight Docker or docker-compose, where recreating a composition or container changes the IP.)

How Pods are scheduled, created, started, restarted if needed, re-scheduled etc... it a much longer story and very broad question.